# ColdFusion 10 IIS Metabase and IIS 6 Configuration compatibility

Tags: c

I’m trying to get CF2016 Dev edition to run on my development system (Windows 10 w/ IIS10).

I have added the following features prior to the installation:

IIS Metabase and IIS 6 Configuration compatibility
.NET Extensibility 3.5
.NET Extensibility 4.6
CGI - ISAPI Extensions
ISAPI Filters

After the installation with all default setting and IIS, I got an error `“Page can’t be displayed”` when I hit http://127.0.0.1:8500/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm.

Using WSconfig, I deleted and re-created a new WS. I got the same error. In IIS, I noticed the CFIDE virtual directory was missing. So, I created the Virtual directory. No more error but all I got was a blank screen.

In windows services, I noticed there are only two services with the coldfusion naming ( ColdFusion 2016 .NET Service and ColdFusion 2016 Add-on Services). Is this correct? I uninstalled CF, and re-installed it with the built-in web server. I still got the error `“Page can’t be display”` when I hit http://127.0.0.1:8500/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm. Again, only noticed the two services above..

I am using CF 2016 on Windows 10 64 bit machine

Comment: What does this have to do with C?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look around and take the [tour], and read through the [help]. You can also read about [ask] a good question.